# Spring REST projection does not kick in

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, projection, spring-restcontroller

I have a domain with uml diagram 
[here](http://www.nomnoml.com/#view/%0A%5BContract%5D%0A%5BConsultant%5D%0A%5BUser%5D%0A%5BRegion%5D%0A%5BInvoice%5D%0A%0A%2F%2F%5BRegion%5D-%5BRegion%5D%0A%5BContract%5Do-*consultants%5BConsultant%5D%0A%5BContract%5Do-*sponsor%5BUser%5D%0A%5BContract%5Do-*coveredRegions%5BRegion%5D%0A%5BUser%5D*-*role%5BApplication%5D%0A%5BInvoice%5D*%2B-%3E1%5BContract%5D).
I have declared `JpaRepository`es for classes: `Invoice, Contract, Consultant, User, Region`
I don't want to expose the repositories as they are because I will need to wrap some business rules around them.
I have defined a few projections and they seem to work with my repositories yet they do not kick in with my `@RestController`

Here is a draft of my wrapper:

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/contractService")
    public class ContractServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<Contract, Long> implements IService<Contract, Long>
    {

        @RequestMapping("/all")
        public List<Contract> all()
        {
            return findAll();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/one", method = GET)
        public Contract one(@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "1") Long id)
        {
            log.info(format("id=%d", id));
            return repository.getOne(id);
        }

        @Autowired
        RepositoryRestConfiguration rrc;

        @RequestMapping("config")
        public List<String> getConfig()
        {
            return rrc.projectionConfiguration()
                .getProjectionsFor(Contract.class)
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey() + "->" + e.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

Here the last method is to verify if projections got configured. i.e.:

```
http://localhost:8080/invoiceapi/contractService/config
```

gets me the result as:

```
[
"brief->interface e.invoice.entity.projection.Brief",
"contractEdit->interface e.invoice.entity.projection.ContractEdit"
]
```

My projection is defined as:

```
@Projection(name="brief", types={Contract.class, Consultant.class, User.class, Region.class})
public interface Brief
{
    public Long getId();
    public String getName();
}
```

Rest calls into repository directly returns me the projected results as desired, id and name only:

```
http://localhost:8080/invoiceapi/contracts?projection=brief
http://localhost:8080/invoiceapi/contracts/1?projection=brief
```

However those into my controller:

```
http://localhost:8080/invoiceapi/contractService/all?projection=brief
http://localhost:8080/invoiceapi/contractService/one?id=2&projection=brief
```

they recursively spider all reachable entities as far as the defined JpaRepositories go. (The Application objects below User do not show up)

My controller returns a document with `Content-Type: application/json` while JpaRepository based one returns a cool looking `Content-Type: application/hal+json`. Their output are different as well: My controller returns a more straightforward output while JpaRepository based one puts associated objects into an array called `_embedded`.

Comment: And why should it be different? You are returning all `Contract` from your `/all` and not a projection and the `/one` returns a `String` instead of a projection. So obviously that is also what you will get back. The `projection` property is pretty much useless as you aren't doing anything with it, for Spring Data Rest this is a trigger to return the specified projection instead of the actual object. If you want to return a projection that return that projection.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understood your explanation. I cannot figure out how I can return a Projection?

Comment: By returning it. Your methods are respectivly returning a `List<Contract>` and a `String`. If you want it to return `Brief` then let it return `Brief` and not another type.

Comment: Let me explain what I understand: If I had to return a Brief then Contract should implement Brief. Let's say I will have another projection, "Detailed".  Obviously Contract will implement that too. I want my all() or one() to return different projections of Contract varying on the client application use cases. In this case I will have to overload my methods one()/all() returning Brief/List<Brief> and Detailed/List<Detailed> . Am I getting it right?

Comment: Or return `Object` and determine inside your method based on the `projection` property. But why do you need this and why isn't it that you can use the spring data rest stuff? I would strongly suggest you take look at the source code and how it is implemented there.

Comment: First, I am new to building a REST based API so I am still trying to understand how things work and that may not be the best solution to what I am trying to achieve:

Comment: For me the current problem is getting different versions of the same object making it into the resulting json document. 3 different use cases: 1) For providing a list of Contracts I need only the id and description. 2) For presenting a Contract as part of an Invoice then I will need id, description and startingDate of the Contract. 3) If I will be editing a Contract on a form for editing then I will require all immediate fields of the Contract c and three other associations Set<Region> c.coveredRegions, Set<Consultant> c.consultants, Set<User> c.sponsors.

Comment: For these associated collections I just need id and name/description of these classes. And in the future, I might have different requirements for how much of an object to include/exclude into a json reply.

Comment: Those are 3 different use cases required 3 different controllers. Don't try to make a I-can-handle-everything-including-the-kitchen-sink-controller.